# How to rewrite this statement in another way?

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, tweetsharp

How to rewrite the following in another way?

```
 OAuthRequestToken requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = OauthToken };
```

Comment: Are you having any problems with it ?

Comment: why do you want to rewrite it?  Is there something wrong with it the way it's written?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with it :(

Comment: Is there any other way to rewrite it so there is no { }?

Comment: This feature is a new language feature of C# that let's you assign variables in a single line.  ChaosPandion provides the correct alternative in the answers.

Comment: Your question would not have beeen downvoted if you had mentioned you were trying to backport to a older version of C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why yes there is. The real question is why would you want to write extra code when the compiler can do it for you?

```
var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken();
requestToken.Token = OauthToken;
```

Comment: Beat you to it by 43 seconds!

Comment: @John - Technically we have 2 different answers. Notice my usage of implicitly typed variable. :)

Comment: @ChaosPandion You're gonna call it a different answer cause you used 'var' instead of 'OAuthRequestToken'?  Haha, I'd say John clearly beat you ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent.

```
OAuthRequestToken requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken();
requestToken.Token =  OauthToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know an new way to write , the following code is anohter way...

```
        OAuthRequestToken requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken();
        requestToken.GetType().GetProperty("Token").SetValue(requestToken, OauthToken, null);
```

Comment: Very.. elegant and eloquent. Nice peace of code!